# How to make a WPF Desktop application accessible over a network

Tags: c#, wpf, network-programming, entity-framework-6, desktop-application

I am designing a WPF application that connects to a MS SQL Server database using Entity Framework.

The application reads data from a Excel file and saves the records to the database. Now the next requirement has come that this application should be accessible to multiple users at the same time (company network) so that all users can see the data in database and query/update it whenever required.

What I am thinking is, all I need to do is just put the database on a central machine which should be on the company's internal network and my application should connect to that database and allow users to perform the operations.

What changes do I require to this current connection string?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TPMSContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TPMSModel.csdl|res://*/TPMSModel.ssdl|res://*/TPMSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Test-DELL;initial catalog=TPMS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And what are other changes that I need to implement/keep in mind for my application to work for multiple users simultaneously?

P.S: My application is "ANY CPU" with targeted framework as 4.5. Right now its Desktop based but in future we might make it web based, but for now we just want it to be Desktop based as it is.

### Update

This is the view of my solution explorer. TMPS is my Main application. TPMS.Data contains my business logic and methods that provides interaction with the database though Entity Framework. TPMS.Entities has the database tables as entity classes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is called 3-tier architecture. You can implement it by WCF TCP/IP hosted on the window.
You will host your Database interaction business logic on other server machine and client will consume these APIs on the other machine.

You need the flowing:

- Create a service(Window) using WCF.
- Host it.
- Generate a proxy (interface or contract).
- Distribute this proxy to clients application who needs to call and use this    APIs.

You can create architecture of your application like below:

- Deployed on the server machine:

  a) Data base Access layer (Interact with database).
  b) Business Logic Layer (It will methods of Data base Access layer).
  c) Service layer (Create WCF Services and call business logic methods here).
  d) Host these into server machine.
- Client Machine -
  a) Create proxy class by using .`svcutil` tool
  b) use this proxy class to client machine for consuming services (APIs)

Reference:

[Host a WCF Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you bro for explaining in details. I have a question. What is the role of WCF here? what will it be doing?
What I thought initially was that if I can put my database on the Server machine and change my connection string a little bit so that it references the database from that server, would not that work? What will be issues in that case? Please elaborate

Comment: Basically, WCF provides API and Hosting of your services on the server. It will interact with your database. Other machines can consume that deployed services from that server. In your case, It will work. But, it will be not 2-tier architecture.

Comment: I updated my question and added snapshot of my solution explorer describing the Data and Entities dlls. TPMS.Data basically contains the edmx and classes to interact with database. TPMS.Entites contains the database table's as classes/entities. 
So I were to transform this into a three tier architecture, how would I go about it? If I create a WCF service, add the Entity Frame Model inside the service (which basically means my TPMS.Data will dissolve into the WCF service. And then Create a Proxy class as you mentioned and write my application. Will that be the correct approach or not?

Comment: Yes.. You will have to deploy services before creating proxy class.